# Python: Find the minimum element in a sorted and rotated array

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to solve [this question](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-element-in-a-sorted-and-rotated-array/).

#### Find the minimum element in a sorted and rotated array

I do not get the min value always. Can someone help? where the issue is. I started coding after many years of gap.   I want to use recursive logic only.

```
def getMin(data,mid, start,end):
    
    if len(data[start:end]) == 1 :
        return data[start]
      
    if len(data[start:end]) == 2:
        if data[start] < data[end]:
            return data[start]
        else:
            return data[end]
    
    if (data[mid] >  data[mid-1] and data[start] > data[end] ):
        #min is i  left array
        start = mid
        end = end
        mid =  int ((start+end)/2)
        #data = data[start:end]
        return getMin(data, mid, start,end)
    else:
        
        #min is in right array
        start = start
        end = mid+1
        mid = int ((start + mid)/2)
        #data = data[start:end]
        return getMin(data, mid, start,end)

def FindMin(data):
    mid = int (len(data)/2)
    end = (len(data)) -1
    start = 0   
    val = getMin(data,mid,start,end)
    return val
    

# Input
import random as rd
numOfElem = 10

data =  sorted(rd.sample (range (1,40),numOfElem))
print ("ONLY Sorted Data is        == ", data)

# get random number to move element by that number
movebysize= rd.randint(1,10)
print ("Move Sorted data by size   == ", movebysize)

# Make array rotated
data = data[movebysize:] + data[:movebysize]
print ("Data Sorted and Rotated is == ", data)

# Find Min:
#data = [[36, 39, 1, 4, 5, 8, 11, 12]]
print (" Min is ==== ", FindMin(data))
```

Comment: The minimum element will always be the element that is less than the element preceding it. If the last element of the list is greater than the first element of the list, then the list has not been rotated.

Comment: I solved it, But I am not sure if this is the cleasn way.

Comment: I solve but not sute if clean way. Updated condition as below :  if ((data[mid] >  data[mid-1] ) 
        and (data[start] > data[end]) 
        and data[mid] < data[mid+1] 
        and data[mid])> data[end]: